# Azure migrate assessment report

Tags: powershell, azure, migration

In the doc https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/migrate/ it has been mentioned that the REST APIs for the new version are not available yet. Is there any preview available? or any powershell script? to get the assessment report programatically

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Github powershell samples for Azure Migrate.

Additionally, there are many powershell scripts available to sample.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-samples/tree/master/azure-migrate